# ASP.NET переменная через тег form получает null, но не должна

Tags: c#, html, asp.net-mvc, entity-framework

MVC, нужно принять из html формы одно выбранное значение из тега select, его значение передает в контролер и должно сохраняться в БД, но NameOfType получает null, не пойму почему

Так выглядит код сущности

```
public class TypeOfOrder
    {
        [Key]
        public int TOOId { get; set; }
        public string NameOFType {get;set;}
    }
```

```
        public ActionResult Index(Client cl,Dates d,Mark m,Models mod,
          Auto a,Orders o,TypeOfOrder too)
        {
            Client CL = new Client();
            Dates D = new Dates();
            Mark MAR = new Mark();
            Models MOD = new Models();
            Orders O = new Orders();
            //TypeOfOrder TOO = new TypeOfOrder();
            
            CL.Name = cl.Name;
            CL.MiddleName = cl.MiddleName;
            CL.SecondName = cl.SecondName;
            CL.Phone = cl.Phone;

            EF.Clients.Add(CL);
            D.Date = DateTime.Now.ToShortDateString();
            EF.Dates.Add(D);
            MAR.NameOfMark = m.NameOfMark;
            EF.Marks.Add(MAR);
            MOD.NameOfModel = mod.NameOfModel;
            EF.Models.Add(MOD);
            O.DescriptionOfProblem = o.DescriptionOfProblem;
            O.Status = "В процессе";
            o.ClientId = CL.ClientId;
                
            if (too.NameOFType=="Мойка") //тут принимает null 
            {
                O.Price = 300;
            }
            else if (too.NameOFType == "Диагностика")
            {
                O.Price = 500;
            }
            else if (too.NameOFType == "Сход-развал")
            {
                O.Price = 900;
            }
            else if (too.NameOFType == "Шиномонтаж")
            {
                O.Price = 400;
            }
            else if (too.NameOFType == "Тех-осмотр")
            {
                O.Price = 1000;
            }
            else
            {
                O.Price = 100;
            }

            EF.Orders.Add(O);
            EF.SaveChanges();

            return View();
        }
```

Так выглядит html form

````
                   <select id="selectInput" name="types">
                        <option name="NameOfType" value="Мойка">Мойка</option>
                        <option name="NameOfType" value="Диагностика">Диагностика</option>
                        <option name="NameOfType" value="Сход-развал">Сход-развал</option>
                        <option name="NameOfType" value="Шиномонтаж">Шиномонтаж</option>
                        <option name="NameOfType" value="Тех-осмотр">Тех-осмотр</option>
                    </select>```
````

Comment: Вы слишком сильно злоупотребляете сокращениями. Такой код очень трудно читать. Так же `if-else-if-else` можно заменить на конструкцию `switch-case`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
<select id="NameOfType" name="NameOfType">
  <option value="Мойка">Мойка</option>
  <option value="Диагностика">Диагностика</option>
  <option value="Сход-развал">Сход-развал</option>
  <option value="Шиномонтаж">Шиномонтаж</option>
  <option value="Тех-осмотр">Тех-осмотр</option>
</select>

    public ActionResult Index(Client cl, Dates d, Mark m, Models mod,
      Auto a, Orders o, String NameOfType)
    {
      ...                 
      if (NameOFType=="Мойка")
        ...
```

Comment: Спасибо, сработало